# Irreducible polynomial has no repeated roots.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

If $F$ is a field of characteristic $0$ and $p(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible, then $p(x)$ has no repeated roots. (Hint: Consider $(p(x),\;p'(x))$).

Let $F$ be a field and $f(x) \in F[X]$, then $f(x)$ has repeated roots if there is a field $E$ containing $F$ and a factorisation in $E[x]$ of the form 
$$f(x)=(x-a)^2h(x).$$

My attempt: If $f(x)$ has repeated roots then $d=\gcd(f,f')\neq 1$ then $0<\deg(d)<n$ and thus $f$ is reducible.

> Is my argument correct and if it is correct then where did I used that $F$ has char $0$ ?

Comment: This might help you: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable1.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You mistyped the inequality, that should have read $0<\deg(d)<n$, but otherwise your argument works; being divisible by such a $d$ (even if of degree$~1$, which is actually quite likely) is sufficient for being reducible. Where you (implicitly) used that the characteristic is $0$ is in assuming that $f'\neq 0$: the (formal) derivative of a polynomial of degree $n>0$ has degree $n-1$ (hence is nonzero) in characteristic$~0$, but this can fail in characteristic$~p$ (namely when $p$ divides $n$).

Answer (score 1):

From $d \neq 1$ it doesn't follow that $1 < \deg d < n$. I don't know why you have that conclusion, but it's just wrong. What you should do is the following: $d = \gcd(f,f') \neq 1$, and since $f$ is irreducible, we must have $d\sim f$. Which shows that $f \mid f'$. Since $\deg f' < \deg f$, we must have $f' =0$. Here's where we use characteristic $0$. Say $f = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$. We have $f' = a_1 + 2a_2x + \cdots + na_n x^{n-1}$. This is $0$, so all the coefficients are $0$, i.e. $ia_i = 0$ for all $1\le i\le n$. If we are in characteristic $p \neq 0$, say $p=2$, from $2a_2 = 0$ we can't conclude $a_2=0$. But since we are in characteristic $0$, $ia_i = 0$ gives $a_i =0$ for each $i$. Hence $f = a_0$. This contradicts the irreducibility of $f$.

Comment: i wrote 1<deg d<n because x-a|d and d|f'